# Possible PHP bug around static:: in PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, static

I was working on some PHP around the "static::" keyword, and encountered an issue where too many static calls result in confusion as to where a method resides. It's easier to show by example:

```
class Class1
{
    function Test()
    {
        return Class2::Test();
    }
}

class Class2
{
    function Test()
    {
        return static::Test2();
    }

    function Test2()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

/* test 1: calling Class1::Test() statically results in expected call to Class2::Test2() */
echo "test 1: " . Class1::Test() . "\n";

/* test 2: instantiating the class causes Class1::Test2() to be called, which does not exist */
$Class1 = new Class1();
echo "test 2: " . $Class1->Test() . "\n";
```

I wanted to reach out and get opinions of PHP experts who can tell me whether this might be a genuine bug or simple misuse of the language.

I realize the setup may be odd with all the static calls, but it represents actual code that I came across.

Please let me know if any more information or clarification is needed. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?  the static keyword wasn't extended until 5.3

Comment: I think he is asking if this is truly a bug with the static keyword and how the whole late static binding thing is "supposed" to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention, running 5.3.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP docs on [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) answer your question.

> "late static bindings work by storing the class named in the last "non-forwarding call". In case of static method calls, this is the class explicitly named (usually the one on the left of the :: operator); in case of non static method calls, it is the class of the object. A "forwarding call" is a static one that is introduced by self::, parent::, static::" ...

Your test 1 is a static call, so when `Class2::Test()` is called, it stores Class2. The static test2 call refers to the correct place in `Class2`.

Your test 2 is a non static call, so it uses the class of the object in all cases, and since it is a `Class1`, it can't find the method `Test2`.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I can see they specifically describe this instance in the documentation. However, now I have to wonder if this is a bug that should be reported? Thoughts?

Comment: @Jeff Why would it be a bug? It seems like this is exactly what they intended. What behavior would you expect and why is it more correct? (You would have to explain that to them in a bug report as well.)

Comment: First, apologies that I am not as well versed in PHP inner workings as many people here. In my example, the code was expected to get the result from Class2::Test2() by way of $Class1->Test() -> Class2::Test() -> Class2::Test2(). Is this a reasonable expectation?

Comment: @Jeff In that case, Class2's Test should use `self::` instead of `static::`.

Comment: what I ended up doing was using the literal class name, e.g.  Class2::Test2() rather than static::Test2(). Using self:: also worked. I was curious if this was something that needs to be addressed in PHP, but that may not be a discussion for here. If y'all want to discuss, I will gladly participate. Otherwise, thanks much for the help!